# How can I make a link direct to an input field?

Tags: javascript, html

Using html (and possibly javascript = but I would prefer not) , I would like to jump from a link in one of my pages to a textbox somewhere near the button, focusing on that section. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to focus on a textbox on click of an element?

```
var d = document;
d.getElementById("myLink").onclick = function() {
    d.getElementById("myTextInput").focus();
};
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/QAnsx/)

Answer (score 3):

Given an input that looks like:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="" />
```

You could make your link automatically jump to that textbox by making the href attribute point to a hash url:

```
<a id="myLink" href="#myInput">Show me the textbox!</a>
```

And wire in javascript(with jQuery in this example) to focus on the textbox when the link is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myLink").click(function(){
        $("#myInput").focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: So we went from preferably not having to use javascript at all to using 229 KB of javascript

Comment: Considering there's no shortage of ways to achieve this and that every other answer uses javascript as well, AND I make it clear jQuery is not required, I don't quite see why I get the -1. There's no reliable way to "focus" on an input without javascript.

Comment: yours was my answer + the jquery function. Totally legit. +1!

Comment: Yes but you can easily do it without jQuery, having that amount of javascript to do such simple task when OP requested minimal amount of scripting is just not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your textbox has an `id` attribute, your link can point to its id with a hash, and the `onclick` can focus it:

```
<a href='#textboxid' onclick='document.getElementById("textboxid").focus();'>Click me</a>
```

When the link is clicked, the page will jump to the textbox's position by the `#textboxid` hash, and its `focus()` method is called to focus it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#myinput">Input Link</a>

<input type="text" value="Text Input" id="myinput" />
```

With HTML using the above code, you'll only be able to jump to the input field.